# Is it faster to run parallel write transactions in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Which is faster for `IndexedDB`?

```
db.transaction("cars", "readwrite").objectStore("cars").add(car);
db.transaction("boats", "readwrite").objectStore("boat").add(boat);
```

or

```
var t = db.transaction(["cars", "boats"], "readwrite");
t.objectStore("cars").add(car);
t.objectStore("boats").add(boat);
```

Comment: if the transactions do not overlap it is absolutely faster. overlap meaning share any of the same object stores.

Comment: if you need acess to both things due to overlap, then it faster usually to use the same transaction but it will not be by a noticeable amount

Comment: I would like to add a point to @Josh comment,when he say about transactions
 overlapping he means different transactions opened on same object store,in such case readonly does not have issue but if readwrite is present then at a time only one transaction can modify the object store.